# Dynamically change text depending on domain ending in php

Tags: php, http

I‘ve been looking for a methode to change the text on my website depending on the domain ending. For example:

If my website ends with a **.ca** I want my text to be: `mydomain.ca`. If it ends with **fr** i want it to be `mydomain.fr`.

What I have found is a way to make this possible via HTTP:

```
if( $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] == 'mydomain.co.uk' ) {
    $text = "Welcome to our UK website";
}
```

However I am not a big fan of this methode since you would have to hardcode it and in my opinion this isn’t best practice. I would be happy for any help which could help to find my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explode the domain.

```php
$parts = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
$text = 'Surfix is: ' . end($parts);
```

Comment: Well, this is a good answer and is definitely better than the one I showed, however, as much as I would think this won't work if my domain is using subdomains... right?

Comment: What you want to get from the subdomain?

Comment: yo its okay thx 4 answer

Comment: This is a completely wrong way to extra a suffix from a domain. If you use normal definitions, the public suffix of `example.co.uk` is `co.uk`, and not `uk`. What you are extracting above is the TLD in its strictest sense, that is top most label under DNS root.